# All from one table in the second table

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to write a query in which I want to check whether all entries from one table are present in some second table.

Eg : I want all entries form table_0 such that all entries from sub-query1 match atleast one entry from sub-query2.

Here is what I tired, but failed.

```
SELECT entries
FROM table_0
WHERE ALL(SELECT entries_1 FROM table_1 WHERE entries_1 = entries) IN (SELECT entries_2 FROM table_2 WHERE PLANET = 'earth');
```

It shows error:

```
syntax error at or near "ALL"
```

I am using postgresql 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try set operstions:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS ((/* subquery 2 */) EXCEPT (/* subquery 1 */))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT entries
FROM table_0
WHERE entries=ALL
(SELECT entries_1 FROM table_1 inner join table_2 on entries_1= entries_2 WHERE PLANET = 'earth');
```